# Source Insight 3.5 shows "Parse Too complex" for a .c file

Tags: c++, c, ide, wireshark, source-insight

everyone. I'm reading the Wireshark source code these days. After importing all wireshark sources into Source Insight 3.50.0072, I found that several .c files can't be parsed correctly. The left "Symbol Window" can't display the local symbols, with a error shows "Parse Too complex in Packet.c(epan)". The file size is not the cause, because many bigger files can be parsed correctly. Also I am using the Git tool to download the Wireshark source trunk and have sucessfully compiled it, so the code is ok. I have tried several versions of Source Insight. Unfortunately they share the same problem.

The web page of the epan/packet.c source code is:
[packet.c](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/packet.c;h=e89ab312df7ebed1adc69c1f6b4061b83c91fac2;hb=HEAD)

The Tsharp.c file has the same problem with the symbol window. So I doubt if this is a bug of Source Insight? How to solve this? Thx.

Comment: Sounds like a limitation in the tool you are using to me. What else could it possibly be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other source code processing tools, with names such as "GCC", "Clang", "Microsoft Visual Studio", "Oracle Studio", "HP aCC", etc., don't seem to have a problem with that file, so I rather strongly believe that this is a deficiency of Source Insight, even if it's not technically a "bug" (perhaps they just have some hardwired limit in the program, so that it's "by design").

And given the number of "Fix: C/C++ ... parsing ..." items in [their change notes](http://www.sourceinsight.com/changes.html), I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that it's Yet Another Bug.

How to solve this?  File a bug with Source Dynamics and tell them you won't buy any more licenses until they fix it, and use some other tool in the interim.

Comment: Hi, I have reported the bug to the official site of Source Insight. I hope they can see that post. BTW, Is there any other good reader for Wireshark source code besides Source Insight and Visual Studio?

Comment: MicroEMACS, that's what I use. :-)  Except on those rare occasions when I'm on Windows (mainly trying to fix Windows-specific issues), in which case I use vi, as I don't have a version of MicroEMACS that works on Windows.  (I.e., being a grumpy old UNIX person, I have no good recommendations for stuff to read the code in any GUI, much less a Windows GUI.)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your code is not properly intended.if you are working on git.do git checkout -- .this will bring the files to the symbol window in source insight.

Answer (score 0):

Options >> Preferences >> Languages >> Project Specific Conditions >> Scan Files >> Ok >> Ok

You will get a dialog box stating -

"You have changed parsing options. Do you want to re-parse ..." .. Click "Yes"

The issue will be solved.